# API Laravel replies instead of an another API Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I develop in this moment two little application with Laravel (two diffrent project).

The first stock of orders in database. This application have an API that returns, via GET, the object order.

Example :

In Postman, I call : http://payment.oo/api/orders/15. My API respond this, and it's ok for me.

```
{
"id": 15,
"client_name": "Mr Doe",
"price": 330.45,
"created_at": "2018-02-07 14:54:07",
"state_id": 2
}
```

The code of this function in api.php

```
Route::post('/orders/{id}', function($id){
        $order = Order::find($id);

        if($order){
            return response()
                ->json($order);
        }
        else{
            abort(404);
        }
    });
```

The second application store also orders and calls the API of the first application to know the status of the payment.

So, in the second application, I stock the ID of payment in database and i call the API of the first application with Guzzle, like this

```
$order = Order::findOrFail($id);
$client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://payment.oo/api/',
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'timeout'  => 2.0,
        ]);
$response = $client->request('GET', 'orders/'.$order->payment_id);
```

That's when I come across a huge problem that I do not understand.

The response to this API request corresponds to a command order of the database of the second application.

```
{
"id":15,
"client_name":"Mr Doe",
"created_at":"2018-02-08 15:02:16",
"take_at":null,
"finish_at":null,
"state_id":1,
"delivery_type_id":1,
"user_id":null,
"payment_id":30
}
```

I use Laragon like development web server

Sorry if I was not clear enough :/ 
And thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you defined your route as `POST` but you're calling it with `GET` using your Guzzle client request.

**Solution**:  whether change the method to `POST` in your client call, or in the first project route file make the Route as a `GET` route.